# Touchscreen virtual for Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, hardware, touch-screen

I have [this](http://htmlkurss.xyz) Website , I want my Website to work on Tablets too, I don't have a tablet... Therefore I am searching for a Virtual Touchscreen or Emulator for Desktops.

Because i have my website to build with [hover Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)  , i will to know how working it on Touchscreen ...

Comment: Please add more information to your question: What  exactly should the emulator do? Emulate a touchscreen in contrast to a mouse? Provide different screen sizes and resolutions? Send a specific user agent string? Emulate a specific operating system, e.g. Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a VirtualBox, install android OS and make sure the the mouse is set to emulate a touchpad in the VirtualBox settings. That should be all you need.

Also look at the following:

The post on 12-01-2017, 08:02 PM, from this site: [Here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-and-cloud-90/virtualbox-android-x86-mouse-integration-invisible-cursor-solution-4175618784/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! , i think the best solution for me... , because later i will to try with Smartphones  , i have not Smartphone , i have a cheap Mobil....

Comment: , how to does it ? , i install Android OS on my Virtualbox , but i to try since 6 hour and i don't know how does it...

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

Comment: thanks, but i have to install Android OS on Virtualbox , my problem is how emulate the Touchscreen...

Comment: VirtualBox does that for you.

Comment: i understand , because Android OS is making for Smartphones ....you to means System + Main Board + USB-Multitouch-Tablet ?

Comment: Yea, that sounds right.